# use a checkbox/button to check all the checkboxes in a table row using Jquery

Tags: jquery

I'm currently using a html table
dynamically built from a database using Jinja2:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}


  <form action="#" method="POST" accept-charset="utf-8" id="myForm">
      <div><label><input id="master" type="checkbox" ></label></div>
    <fieldset id ="slaves">
    <div class="table">
    <table cellspacing="0" table id="table">
      <caption>Please select the survey sections you would like to complete</caption>
      <colgroup span="19"></colgroup>
        <tr>
          <th scope="col">Organization</th>
          <th scope="col">Survey Header</th>
          <th scope="col">Period name</th>
          <th scope="col">Completed</th>
          <th scope="col">Due</th>
          <th scope="col">check all</th>
          <th scope="col">1</th>
          <th scope="col">2</th>
          <th scope="col">3 </th>
          <th scope="col">4</th>
          <th scope="col">5</th>
          <th scope="col">6</th>
          <th scope="col">7</th>
          <th scope="col">8</th>
          <th scope="col">9</th>
          <th scope="col">10</th>
          <th scope="col">11</th>
          <th scope="col">12</th>
          <th scope="col">13</th>
          <th scope="col">14</th>
          <th scope="col">15</th>
          <th scope="col">16</th>
          <th scope="col">17</th>
        </tr>
        {% set oshp = (0,0,0) %}
        {% set start = True %}
          {% for  survey_table in survey_tables %}


            {% if survey_table.completed != None %}
                {% set color = "#DCF8FF" %}
            {% else %}
                {% set color = "#FFEBF4" %}
            {% endif %}


            {% if oshp != (survey_table.organization, survey_table.survey_header,
                survey_table.period_name)  %}
                {% set oshp = (survey_table.organization, survey_table.survey_header,
                survey_table.period_name)  %}
                <tr>
                    <td>{{ survey_table.organization }}</td>
                    <td>{{ survey_table.survey_header }}</td>
                    <td>{{ survey_table.period_name }}</td>
                    <td>{{ survey_table.completed }}</td>
                    <td>{{ survey_table.due }}</td>

                    <div><label><td BGCOLOR="{{ color }}"><input type="checkbox"  name="{{ survey_table.user_survey_section_id}}" value="{{ survey_table.user_survey_section_id  }}" title= "{{ survey_table.survey_section }}" ><label></td></div>
            {% else %}
            <div><label><td BGCOLOR="{{ color }}"><input type="checkbox"  name="{{ survey_table.user_survey_section_id}}" value="{{ survey_table.user_survey_section_id  }}" title= "{{ survey_table.survey_section }}" ></td></label></div>
            {% endif %}
          {% endfor %}
                </tr>
    </table>
    </div>
    </fieldset>
    <input class="bigbutton" type="submit" value="Submit" >
  </form>


{% endblock %}
```

I'm looking to add the ability to select all by row.

to be explicit

```
row 1[select all button] [ ] [ ] [ ] [ ]
row 2[select all button] [ ] [ ] [ ] [ ]

if row 1 selected all button clicked:
row 1[select all button] [x] [x] [x] [x]
row 2[select all button] [ ] [ ] [ ] [ ]
```

I'm new to jquery and was hoping to stumble across a plugin or a simple tutorial directed at this specific case. Its possible that i need to lose the table as my data isn't necessary tabular, in which case i could use any number of [examples with fieldsets](http://briancray.com/posts/check-all-jquery-javascript)  What do more experienced Jquery users suggest?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You first have to add class to every "select all checkbox", so you can later bind click event only on those checkboxes. Lets say you add class="checkall", for example.

[Here is a working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hStXd/)

```
$(".checkall").click(function(){
$(this).parents('tr').find(':checkbox').prop('checked', this.checked);
});
```

In answer from Logan, you can only click the select all checkbox once and it can`t be deselected later, because value (true) is hardcoded. I think you should use this.checked instead.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the checkbox is in the same row, you want to traverse the dom path upwards to the containing tr. From there you want to find all checkboxes and mark them as checked.

```
$('.row-check-all-input').on('click', function(){
  $(this).parents('tr').find('input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked', true); 
});
```

Example in JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2bF3D/

Comment: I tried to play with the code you added, i think i understand it for the most part. Still when i added it i couldn't get the desired behavior (nothing happened) here is a look at the page source: http://bpaste.net/show/94783/