# jQuery - checkboxes selecting all on a row or with similar names & ID's

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, checkbox

Using jQuery 1.9.1 & getting XML returned from a query that needs to be displayed in a web page as shown in the picture below.  I had asked a similar question several days ago but was all over the place in what I was asking.  Hope to ask better questions this time.

[image: Equipment for Class Room - how it needs to be displayed on the screen]

For the items in the picture, the XML input would be:

```
<Classrooms>
    <Room Number="3">
        <Machine>310</Machine>
        <Machine>320</Machine>
        <Machine>340</Machine>
        <Machine>350</Machine>
    </Room>
    <Room Number="8">
        <Machine>810</Machine>
        <Machine>820</Machine>
        <Machine>840</Machine>
    </Room>
    <Room Number="10">
        <Machine>1010</Machine>
        <Machine>1020</Machine>
    </Room>
</Classrooms>
```

The code below is a function that is called upon a successful `AJAX GET` and builds the `checkboxes` in a table on the web page.

```
var $roomList = $( items );
var roomListString = jQ_xmlDocToString( $roomList );
var roomListXML = $.parseXML(roomListString);

$(roomListXML).find("Row").each(function() {
    var activeRooms = $( roomListXML ).find("Row").text();
    var nbrRooms = $(activeRooms).find("Room").size();
    $(activeRooms).find("Room").each(function() {
        var roomNo = $(this).attr("Number");
        var roomchk = "Room"+roomNo;
        var $tr = $("<tr />");
        $tr.append('<td><input type="checkbox" name="'+roomchk+'" id="'+roomchk+'" class="checkall" /><label for="'+roomchk+'">Room '+roomNo+'</td>');
        $("#mytable").append( $tr );

        $(this).children().each(function() {
            var machID = $(this).text();
            var idname = "Room"+roomNo+"Mach"+machID;
            $tr.append('<td><input type="checkbox" name="'+idname+'" id="'+idname+'" /><label for="'+idname+'">'+machID+'</td>');
            $("#mytable").append( $tr );
            });
        });
    });
```

When the above code is run on the data, the `HTML` in the table is as shown below.

```
<tbody>
   <tr>
     <td>
       <input name="Room3" id="Room3" class="checkall" type="checkbox" />
       <label for="Room3">Room 3</label>
     </td>
     <td>
       <input name="Room3Mach310" id="Room3Mach310" type="checkbox" />
       <label for="Room3Mach310">310</label>
     </td>
     <td>
       <input name="Room3Mach320" id="Room3Mach320" type="checkbox" />
       <label for="Room3Mach320">320</label>
     </td>
     <td>
       <input name="Room3Mach340" id="Room3Mach340" type="checkbox" />
       <label for="Room3Mach340">340</label>
     </td>
     <td>
       <input name="Room3Mach350" id="Room3Mach350" type="checkbox" />
       <label for="Room3Mach350">350</label>
     </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td>
       <input name="Room8" id="Room8" class="checkall" type="checkbox" />
       <label for="Room8">Room 8</label>
     </td>
     <td>
       <input name="Room8Mach810" id="Room8Mach810" type="checkbox" />
       <label for="Room8Mach810">810</label>
     </td>
     <td>
       <input name="Room8Mach820" id="Room8Mach820" type="checkbox" />
       <label for="Room8Mach820">820</label>
     </td>
     <td>
       <input name="Room8Mach840" id="Room8Mach840" type="checkbox" />
       <label for="Room8Mach840">840</label>
     </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td>
       <input name="Room10" id="Room10" class="checkall" type="checkbox" />
       <label for="Room10">Room 10</label>
     </td>
     <td>
       <input name="Room10Mach1010" id="Room10Mach1010" type="checkbox" />
       <label for="Room10Mach1010">1010</label>
     </td>
     <td>
       <input name="Room10Mach1020" id="Room10Mach1020" type="checkbox" />
       <label for="Room10Mach1020">1020</label>
     </td>
   </tr>
</tbody>
```

Selection of any checkbox on the page will enable a `SUBMIT` button on the page, which when clicked will pass the value of the boxes checked into another function.  The user can select any number of the individual boxes (the ones with the number beside them), regardless of the room those items are associated with.  When the user selects a Room checkbox though, **ALL** the individual checkboxes for that room should also be checked. The individual values are the ones I want.  When the `SUBMIT` button is clicked, the individual values are all that will be sent to that function.

I had [looked at this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16260041/use-a-checkbox-button-to-check-all-the-checkboxes-in-a-table-row-using-jquery) about using a checkbox `class` to select all.

I'm using the code below to find what's checked.  I can see when I select an individual box that it gets added to the array.  I can also see when I select a Room that the `checkall` is found, but I can't seem to make the individual checkboxes get checked once I do.  I had been attempting to use the [Attribute Starts With](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/?rdfrom=http://docs.jquery.com/mw/index.php?title=Selectors/attributeStartsWith&redirect=no#attributevalue) jQuery selector, but haven't been able to get it to check the boxes.

```
$("#mytable").click(function(e) {
    var ele = $(this).find(":checkbox");
    var zall = $(this).find(":checkbox.checkall:checked");
    if (zall) {
        var zname = $(zall).attr("name");
        var selectallmachines = "input[name^='" + zname +"']:checked:enabled";
        $( $(selectallmachines), "#mytable");
        }
    var arr = [];
    $(":checkbox:checked").each(function(i) {
        arr[i] = $(this).val();
        });
    });
```

I'm sure that it is something that I'm overlooking, but what am I missing?  Would appreciate any suggestions or guidance on what I'm doing wrong, or if there's perhaps a better way to do what I'm doing.

Thanks!

Comment: You have a good question there OP but it's buried in a lot of wordiness, could you crack together a JSFiddle for us?

Comment: Also,it can help for you to point out that you just want to figure out minus the details of how you created the checkboxes.  From what I am understanding, you just want a list of checkboxes which all have a master checkbox for "select/unselect all" capabilities. Correct?

Comment: You are misusing IDs, you definitely want classes. You basically want to do something like <input type="checkbox" class="room" data-number="3"> then for the machines <input type="checkbox" name="..." class="room_3"> then to check all machines in a room it's just $('.room').click(function() { $('.' + $(this).data('number')).prop('checked', this.checked); });

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this

```
$('.checkall').change(function(){
   $('input[id^='+this.id+']').prop('checked',this.checked);
});
```

when `.checkall` is clicked/changes - set checked property on all inputs with an id that starts with the current clicked elements `id`

<kbd>[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/QywNK/)</kbd>

Though you probably should delegate since you are using ajax to get the elements - this is assuming `#mytable` exists on DOM Ready - or replace with an ancestor element that does

```
$('#mytable').on('click','.checkall',function(){
     $('input[id^='+this.id+']').prop('checked',this.checked);
});
```

another alternative is to give the checkall id as a class to the relative checkboxes

```
$tr.append('<td><input type="checkbox" name="'+idname+'" id="'+idname+'" class="'+roomchk+'"/><label for="'+idname+'">'+machID+'</td>');
```

then you can do

```
$('#mytable').on('click','.checkall',function(){
     $('input.'+this.id).prop('checked',this.checked);
});
```

<kbd>[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/RBVdf/)</kbd>

Comment: Thank you - I used your last example (assigning the checkall id as a class to the relative checkboxes) and it works for my example.  Thanks for the help!